# I try to draw the figure by using Tikz,but can't

Tags: tikz-pgf

It know how to draw simple circle using TikZ. But this is little bit trickier for me.

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436).  It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem.  This should show what you have tried so far and point out exactly what you are stuck at. You said you can draw the circles, so at least you could provide that as a MWE.

While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is what appears to be a complete solution but the OP has not accepted it.

Answer (score 17):

It seems we are eager to close/downvote some times and some times not. In this episode of free time/getting bored, this answer is presented as a drawing service (which may not be the case always, hence show some effort in future).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns}


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
%circles
\draw[pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[fill=white] (0,0) circle (1cm);
% axis
\draw[dashed] (-4,0) -- (4,0);
\draw[dashed] (0,4) -- (0,-4);
%arrows and nodes
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- node[above=1mm,scale=0.8]{$r_a$}(45:1cm);
\draw[-latex] (0,0) -- node[pos=0.7,above=1mm,scale=0.8]{$r_b$}(30:2cm);
\node[scale=0.7,anchor=south east] at (0,0) {O};
\draw[-latex] (225:2mm) -- node[pos=0.25,below=1mm,scale=0.8]{$p_a$} (225:1cm);
\draw[-latex] (225:2.8cm) -- node[pos=0.75,below=1mm,scale=0.8]{$p_b$} (225:2cm);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: "In this episode of free time/getting bored…" Classic. :)

Comment: I assumed everyone used this as a means of procrastination... but maybe it is only me ;).

Comment: Wait til they get the invoice...

Comment: Maybe `pattern color=gray!50` could make this a bit more legible?

Comment: @A.Ellett That is a nice suggestion. I was trying to follow the picture from OP.

Comment: I’d suggest `\draw[even odd rule, pattern=north west lines] (0,0) circle [radius=2] circle[radius=1];`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel That is a shorter way of which I thought of but for beginner's, I wanted code to be less cryptic. Thanks for the comment :-)